# Can I generate a WSDL file without binding and service information?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, sap-basis, netweaver

I came across an issue where a customer is able to open a SAP WSDL using net-beans as well as in .NET but not in SOAPUI.

When I checked the WSDL I found that service as well as binding tags are not defined or no such tags included. WSDL ends with port-type information.

In SOAPUI, I got an error like no content in the file and when I try to open it in Eclipse, I am able to open it using web explorer window, but service as well binding information fields are empty. I could see `ws-policy` elements in customer's WSDL.

1. How he might have produced a WSDL without binding and service information?
2. What would be the reason he is telling it is working in .NET?

   I am not sure about .NET tools.
3. Is there any web service client tool which can open the operations without endpoint /service information and send request/response ?..

please help
thank you for your time.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how to generate such a WSDL file (as your headline suggests) or how to work with such a file? Your "question" does not even contain a question mark... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only know a bit about the first question, can't help you with the other ones...

You can request two "flavors" of WSDL from a NW/ABAP system. This is related to the fact that the implementation (programming) of the service is usually performed on a different system and by different people than the configuration of the service.

After the service (or rather a service definition) has been implemented, you can get what's called a "design-time WSDL document". This document does not include the endpoint information - it cannot, because that would require technical information about the target system landscape and its configuration that is simply not available yet.

From the service definition, an administrator can create a configuration. This includes the binding information as well as stuff like base URL, security settings, transport layer settings and so on. With this configuration, you can generate a second WSDL document that contains the actual endpoint configuration.

[image: WSDL generation in SOAMANAGER]