# Could not connect to host - try to setup connection from SAP to Magento

Tags: web-services, magento, soap, wsdl

I need to setup a connection from SAP to Magento (unidirectional).
From the SAP part I get a WSDL file and a message (XMLfile with specific data) which is sent via SOAP. My problem is to receive the data which comes with the XML.

My attempt is to load the WSDL file, try to get a connection and load a delivered method.

You can see my attempts here:

```
$wsdl = 'url-to-the-wsdl.wsdl'; 

try {

    $client = @new SOAPClient($wsdl);  
    $response = $client->method();

} catch (Exception $e) {  

    echo $e->getMessage(); 

}

die(var_dump($response));
```

The problem is I still get the error Message:

> Could not connect to host

Honestly I'm still confused if this is the right way to get this done. If anyone could give me a hint that at least this part is correct so far I would be relieved. If not, any suggestions or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check whether the WSDL file includes the binding information (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975618/can-i-generate-a-wsdl-file-without-binding-and-service-information)

Comment: Hello @vwegert yes the binding is included.